# onmouseover em menu dropleft

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, dropdown

Olá, sou novo na área de programação e minha dúvida pode parecer um pouco boba para quem temmais experiência, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o efeito mouseover funcionar no menu dropleft (bootstrap).

Já tentei usar tags de javascript e até mudar a função das variáveis, mas não tive sucesso.

Vou deixar aqui um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer.

PS: Não estou usando a tag UL pois é para o menu de ícones aparecer todo a esquerda, e não em lista, abaixo.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Dropleft</h1>
<div>   
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
</td>
<td>
<!-- Default dropleft button -->
<div class="btn-group dropleft">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dne4i5cb88590.cloudfront.net/invisionpower-com/reactions/react_like.png" width="32" height="32" /></a>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu"><center> &nbsp;
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dne4i5cb88590.cloudfront.net/invisionpower-com/reactions/react_haha.png" width="32" height="32" /></a> &nbsp; 
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dne4i5cb88590.cloudfront.net/invisionpower-com/reactions/react_confused.png" width="32" height="32" /></a> &nbsp; 
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dne4i5cb88590.cloudfront.net/invisionpower-com/reactions/react_sad.png" width="32" height="32" /></a> &nbsp;  </center>  
  </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se vc está usando Bootstrap, vc tem que seguir o que diz a documentação dele, usar as mesmas tags e os mesmo atributos se não não vai funcionar https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ essa é a documentação que vc deve seguir!

Comment: Eu li a documentação amigo, não fala nada sobre o comando onmouseover na referência de dropdown e nem em outras referências, pois pesquisei o site todo antes de vir aqui pedir ajuda... Se fosse simples, pode ter certeza que eu não estaria aqui...

Comment: Fiz um esforço para responder, mas sua pergunta precisaria ser mais clara. O comentário do colega acima pode não ter te ajudado, mas a intenção era sim ajudar. Ele não entendeu a pergunta porque ela está apresentada de maneira confusa.

Answer (score 2):

É com CSS que você faz isso, não com JavaScript:

```css
.dropleft .dropdown-menu a {
    display: inline-block; /* para a imagem afetar a altura do a */
}

.dropleft .dropdown-menu a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```